# How to understand mysql inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as below:

```
users = select * from users where group_id = 1 and track_id = "xxxxxx";
user_ids = [user.id for user in users]
tickets = select * from tickets where group_id = 1 and user_id in (user_ids);
```

`users` and `tickets` tables all have the `group_id` field.

The index of users table are on `group_id` and `track_id` fields;
The index of tickets table are on `group_id` and `user_id` fields.

I want to merge two sql to one.

```
select * from tickets join users on tickets.user_id = users.id
where tickets.group_id = 1 and users.track_id = "xxxxx";
```

or

```
select * from tickets join users on tickets.user_id = users.id
where users.group_id = 1 and users.track_id = "xxxxx";;
```

Is it right? which is better? I how what is the meaning of inner join, but I want to know I should use `tickets.group_id` or `users.group_id`? What is the difference?

How to understand mysql inner join? How does it works?

Comment: You may want to start with their documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @Siyual What does this have to do with inner vs. outer join?

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't - but the answers within clearly answer his question of how inner joins work.

Comment: @Siyual Which answer would tell him whether he needs to use `where tickets.group_id = 1` or `where users.group_id = 1`? That's his question.

Comment: @Barmar I see that is his question now, but that wasn't clear at the time - I can remove it.

Comment: sorry for my unclear description.

Comment: One of two things: you may be missing Join criteria if group_ID uniquely identifies a user and a ticket then why wouldn't the join criteria include group_ID?  `on tickets.user_ID = users.id and users.group_Id = tickets.group_ID` then it doesn't matter which you use.  OR you need to filter on both because they mean different things.  So in user I could have a group_ID 1 and in tickets a group_ID of 4.  But if BOTH are ALWAYS the same, then you're missing join criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test *both* `group_id` fields, just like you do in the queries that you're merging.

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets AS t
JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE t.group_id = 1
AND u.group_id = 1
```

Comment: It would really depend on what he is looking for. If he wants all tickets for group 1 regardless of what group the user is in, then `t.group_id = 1` is the only thing needed in the `where`

Comment: @CptMisery Look at the original queries that he wants to merge. He used `users.group_id = 1` to get the list of user IDs, and then `tickets.group_id = 1` when getting the tickets belonging to those users. To get the equivalent effect, he needs to test them both in the join.

Comment: @Barmar you are right! If both group_id, I found mysql scan the less rows, two tables all use the index.

Answer (score 1):

Consider additional join criteria:  If the group_ID will always be the same in both tables then you should add group_ID as join criteria and filter by either or.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets join users 
  on tickets.user_id = users.id
 and tickets.group_ID = users.group_ID
WHERE tickets.group_id = 1 and users.track_id = "xxxxx";
```

Alternatively you must filter based on both: because group_ID could be different than the ticket_ID, you must filter by both.

This most accurately represents the union of your two queries. if the group_ID is not the same for tickets and users when joined.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets join users 
  on tickets.user_id = users.id
WHERE tickets.group_id = 1 
  and users.group_id = 1 
  and users.track_id = "xxxxx";
```

Logically however, we would need to understand the purpose of "GROUP_ID" in both tables.  What is the functional purpose of each?  I can envision selling off groups of tickets... but I don't see how a user could be in a static group as depending on the event, a user could be in more than one group over time.

Perhaps you shouldn't have group_ID in both tables?  Perhaps you needa  user Groups table...

If the two groups represent different fundamental attributes of the entity, then they must be evaluated separately; thus the 2nd query makes the most sense.    However if they represent the same entity attribute then adding to the join criteria makes more sense

Comment: nice answer! I think for tickets table, the group_id is not needed. But I remove the group_id from tickets, mysql will scan the all ticket rows.

Comment: The users group_id represent a user belongs a group; for the tickets group id, If I want to get a group users tickets, I can do like this: `select * from tickets where group_id = 1;` users and tickets just an example.

Comment: I still don't understand the functional purpose of both.  perhaps the data base design is a bit off?.  Maybe a user belongs to a group today. buys a ticket, later they belong to a different group and buy a ticket thus the group_ID value in tickets for each user represents the group ID at the moment in time the user made the purchase? Again, not enough functional information to know how/why groups are used thus two potential join answers.  Is GROUP_ID a FK to a table called Group in both cases with a ID as it's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Your first query will give you all tickets for group 1 and the users could be in any group. The second query will give you all tickets for users in group 1 even if the ticket is in group 2.